# How to determine the value of c where the linear system is inconsistent for some vector b

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question:**

Suppose that the linear system $$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & c & 1 \\ 1 & 3 & -2 \end{bmatrix} \vec{x}=\vec{b}= \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{bmatrix}$$ is **inconsistent** for some vector $\vec{b}$. Determine c.

$$\color{crimson}{------------------------------------------}$$

**What I did:**

I put this into RREF and got :

$$\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r} 2 & 0 & -1 & x_1\\ 0 & c & 1 & x_2 \\ 0 & 2+c & 0 & 2x_3-x_1+x_2 \end{array}\right]$$

I do not know what to do next.

Comment: When do you get a row of all zero coefficients? (If you already know determinants, that is another option.)

Comment: @DanielFischer c=-2 ? :D

Comment: @DanielFischer but $b$ could be the zero vector right? No restriction has been mentioned in the question

Comment: The question is when the system "is inconsistent for **some** vector $b$". Every linear system with right hand side $0$ is consistent. Also every system without a zero coefficient row in the RREF. The question is when you can find *some* $b$ such that the system is inconsistent.

Comment: @DanielFischer thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system is inconsistent for some vector $b$ if and only if its rank is $<3$, since any system of rank $3$ is consistent, i. e. the linear map associated with the matrix of the system is an isomorphism.

Let's row reduce the matrix of the system:
$$\begin{bmatrix}2&0&-1\\0&c&1\\1&3&-2\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}2&0&-1\\0&c&1\\0&6&-3\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}2&0&-1\\0&6&-3\\0&c&1\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}2&0&-1\\0&6&-3\\0&0&3c+6\end{bmatrix} $$
We see the system has rank $<3$ (and indeed has rank $2$) if and only if $3c+6=0$, i. e. $\,c=-2$.